# How do bounce rate and page views change Alexa rankings?

Tags: google, alexa

My site has 30,000 visits with 86,000 page views. If the bounce rate of 54%, then does it means only 15,000 users generated the 86,000 page views or 30,000 visits generated the 86,000 page views.

My website is www.cricandcric.com

Even though I have got 86,000 page views, my site's Alexa ranking is still getting worse day by day. How do I control that?

Answer (score 3):

Pageviews and visits are different measurements, so there is no exact one to one relationship. Furthermore, when any stat gathering service counts a pageview or a visit can vary. (Does a page view count when any part of the page loads, or only after the whole page loads, or does 50% have to load, etc. Same thing for visits.)

IF (and and that is a big IF) both stats are measured the same, then each visit generates one initial page view. Then, 54 percent of them bounce. Most likely, they leave your website altogether. The remaining 46% are the ones who generate most of the rest of the pageviews. (Users who bounce usually bounce away. Users who don't bounce are more likely to view another page.)

So, one could infer an approximation from your statistics that 30,000 people (or bots that look like people) generate 30,000 page views. Then, 54% (16,200) people bounce back to Google or whence they came, and the remaining 46% (14,800) people go on to view an average of 3.78 pages each.

Your Alexa ranking **is relative** to other sites, so if other sites are getting more than 86,000 page views your ranking will be dropping even if your stats stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your Alexa ranking to go up just install the toolbar and visit your site every day. If you want it to go up higher have your friends do the same thing.

FYI, Alexa's rating is inaccurate and useless. It's the last thing you should be worrying about. Why not focus your time and attention on something that actually matters and will improve your website and actually bring in traffic?