# bounce rate and Alexa ranking clarifications

Tags: google, seo, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bounce rate and Alexa ranking clarifications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/bounce-rate-and-alexa-ranking-clarifications)

30000 visits with 86000 pageviews, if there is a bounce rate of 54%, then does it means
only 15000 users generated the 86000 page views or 30000 visits generated the 86000 page views.

My website is [redacted]

Even though i have got 86000 page views, my site alexa ranking is still reducing day by day.
can any one suggest how to control that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/7396/8359

Answer (score 2):

1) No. It still means 30000 visits generated 86000 pageviews. Bounce rate means how many visits were single pageviews. In your case, the numbers mean

`30000*56% = 16800` visits were single pageviews

and hence

`30000*44% = 13200` visits resulted in 86000-16800= 69200 pageviews.

2) Alexa rankings are relative. Overall worldwide internet pageviews are increasing day by day. So your pageviews could remain constant (or even increase) and still your ranking could drop.