# What exactly is "bounce rate" on the site info from Alexa?

Tags: alexa, bounce-rate, page-views

I see here http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com in section "How engaged are visitors to google.com?" exsist 3 parameter:

- **Bounce Rate**
- **Daily Pageviews per Visitor**
- **Daily Time on Site**

"Daily Pageviews per Visitor" = how much pages user open e.g. can open 3 page from domain.com or can leave page without open any new page.

"Daily Time on Site" = this mean how much time people spend on website.

My question, "bounce rate" is maked from this 2 parameter and depends of this 2 parameter or bounce rate is separately calculated by some other parameter?

Comment: See also: [How do bounce rate and page views change Alexa rankings?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-do-bounce-rate-and-page-views-change-alexa-rankings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer to the Bounce rate concept [has been answered before, here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9897/how-does-google-calculate-bounce-rate).

From [Google Analytics Help Center](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en):

> Bounce rate is the percentage of single-page visits or visits in which
>   the person left your site from the entrance (landing) page.
>
> There are a number of factors that contribute to a high bounce rate. For example, users might leave your site from the entrance page if there are site design or usability issues. Alternatively, users might also leave the site after viewing a single page if they've found the information they need on that one page, and had no need or interest in going to other pages.

In reply to your question, yes, it's calculated separately because in fact it has nothing to do with those 2 other metrics you point: it's just an independent percentage of how many users arrive and leave your site without seeing more than one page.
The time a user stays doesn't matter, a user can open your page and allow the session to timeout (30min by GA default) and will still be counted as a Bounce if he only sees one page.

Comment: Wow I actually didn't know this.

Comment: How does this affect one page designs?  Or is bounce rate not necessarily a bad thing? What is the correlation between bounce rate and SEO rank? If that makes sense.

Comment: Google has said they do not use bounce rate as measured by Google Analytics as a ranking factor.  I believe that they do use "bounce back rate" as in "the percentage of users that hit the back button to the search results".  See [my full answer to "Does a site's bounce rate influence Google rankings?"](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13920/does-a-sites-bounce-rate-influence-google-rankings/54336#54336) for an in depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually slightly re-define that to "the percentage of single-page visits in which the person left the site ***without interacting with the page***".

This is due to the fact that interaction events will prevent single-page sessions counting as a bounce. For example, if you have a video on a page that a user lands on and you track their video play as an interaction, if they leave the site after viewing, this will not count as a bounce.

Comment: In Google Analytics you have to set up [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) to track interactions.   While you answer is correct, I would add that such events are not enabled by default with installation of the Google Analytics tracking code.

Comment: The question is asking about bounce rate as measured by Alexa.   Although I can't find documentation from them about it, they likely measure bounce rate using their toolbar and look at the number of single pageview sessions to your site.  Even if you set up interactions to measure bounce rate more intelligently in your analytics, Alexa will not pick up on that.